# Dynamic price setting in the WooCommerce payment section or in the cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce 3rd party plugin project. This plugin offers customizations for products.

As an example, let's say the price of the product is 10 units. When you request an additional feature, the price of the product, which will be + 5 units, is 10 units, but it has to pay 15 units during payment.

I tried the following functions separately and could not get a result.

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', function( $cart_object ) { 
    foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $key => $value ) {
        $value['data']->set_price( 50 );
        $value['data']->price += 50;
    }
}, 10 ); 


add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_product_subtotal', function( $product_subtotal ) { 
    return $product_subtotal + 20; 
}, 10, 4 ); 


WC()->cart->set_fee_total( 50 );
```

https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Cart.html

I also tried the "set" methods on this page. But I couldn't get results. Can you help me?

Comment: Sorry but the first function still perfectly works on last woocommerce version… see [those related threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=woocommerce_before_calculate_totals)

Comment: I tried it on admin-ajax.php it didn't work woocommerce use with add-to-car = id ca tried.

Comment: So that means that you don't do it in the right way…